# Template Compiler Error (TemplateCompiler) in ember-paper/templates/components/paper-dialog.hbs

Tags: npm, ember.js, build, ember-cli, ember-paper

My ember application started showing below error while building the app (Initially it was working and without any code change, build started failing):

*Template Compiler Error (TemplateCompiler) in ember-paper/templates/components/paper-dialog.hbs

Assertion Failed: The {{in-element}} helper cannot be used. ('ember-paper/templates/components/paper-dialog.hbs' @ L1:C0)*

I am using `"ember-cli": "^3.28.3"` and `"ember-paper": "^1.0.0-beta.30"`

Ember latest 4.0 [release](https://blog.emberjs.com/ember-4-0-released/) showing renderTemplate is removed in favor of {{in-element}} or other rendering target. Is this API removal is the culprit?

Any clue or suggestion will help. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: what is your `ember-source` version?

in-element wasn't added to ember-source until 3.20: https://blog.emberjs.com/ember-3-20-released/

Comment: ember-source is 3.18.1. @NullVoxPopuli Do you think ember-source version is correct?

Comment: your error makes sense then! you have to upgrade to 3.20

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the solution was in a comment and is "to upgrade a dependency"

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli Upgrading the ember-source to 3.20 fixed this issue. Thank you for the quick support.

Comment: yay! I'm glad!!